# In a custom task in my buildSrc folder: How do I determine the file path of the subproject it is called in?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

**If I define a custom gradle task in buildSrc: How do I find out the relative path to the project from which the task is called?**

In my buildSrc folder, I have a custom task that creates a Enum our of my message.properties file:

```
open class GenerateEnumTask : DefaultTask() {

    @get:Input
    open var inputFolder: String = "src/main/resources"

    @get:Input
    open val targetFilePath: String = "src/generated/kotlin/MessageCode.kt"

    @get:OutputFile
    val enumFile = File(targetFilePath)

    @TaskAction
    fun generateEnum() {
     ...
    }

    @Internal
    override fun getDescription() = "This task uses downloaded property files and creates an enum kotlin file"
}
```

I then want to make sure the enum is generated before code compilation. 
So I put this in the subproject "core", where I need the Enum.

build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks {
    val generateEnumTask by registering(GenerateEnumTask::class)

    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = Versions.jvmTarget
        dependsOn(generateEnumTask)
        dependsOn(formatKotlin)

        doFirst{
            println("compile kotlin in core project")
        }

    }


}
```

This does indeed work if I run `gradle compileKotlin` directly from the subfolder of the core project.
However, if I run the same command from the **root** project, the code searches for a src folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the answer was simple: [DefaultTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) inherits from AbstractTask, which has a reference to the project that the task was called in (getProject)

This works nicely:

```
open var targetFolder: String = this.project.file("src/main/resources").absolutePath
```